# Which JDBC drivers support scroll sensitive/insensitive properly?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, stream, buffering

I just found out that the Postgres Java JDBC driver does not really support the `SCROLL_SENSITIVE`/`SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` modes using streaming, but instead simulates those modes by loading the full result set into client memory all at once. For queries with a big result set, that can lead to an unexpectedly huge memory usage, especially in a language like Java with little support for unboxed values. When using `FORWARD_ONLY` mode, the driver streams the results as expected.

([details](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/query.html#query-with-cursor); From my understanding this is a limitation of the Postgres wire protocol, though the driver could maybe in theory work around that by converting queries into explicit cursors.)

To prevent such surprises in the future, I'm wondering how wide spread such behavior is and which other common JDBC drivers do not implement real scrolling where that would be expected, so I know to watch out for that if I happen to use one of those drivers. Which other common JDBC drivers do not support all of the scrolling modes in a streaming fashion?

Comment: JDBC is filled with differences between databases and sometimes even between drivers (not driver versions) for the same database. It's too broad to start listing them here.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Are you looking to find other drivers that do the same as the driver you've specified here? Or alternative drivers that do not? Certainly, all drivers are not created equal. You might try [the ones from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-postgres/). Databases differ too; [Virtuoso comes from my employer](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the intent. I'm looking for drivers that do not implement streaming scrolling similar to the postgres driver, so I know to watch out for such behavior if I happen to be using one of those drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL/MariaDB is slightly worse than Postgres. Like Postgres it will buffer the entire query result by default. Also like Postgres it can only do forward scrolling without buffering, but unlike Postgres the database connection is occupied while a query result has not been exhausted and cannot be used for other queries at the same time. Any locks and other resources are also held until the result set has been exhausted, so leaving a result set open for a long time is not recommended. [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html#ResultSet)

Oracle streams results by default, but the server or network protocol does not support scrolling backwards. The JDBC driver emulates scrolling by caching the results if `SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` or `SCROLL_SENSITIVE` is set. So other than the default this is similar to Postgres. [ref](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28611)